# After upgrading an Xamarin UWP app to Maui the new update refuses to install

Tags: maui, winui-3, xamarin.uwp

This is pretty much exactly what is occurring for me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1000760/migrate-uwp-app-to-maui-windows-error-after-update?comment=question#newest-question-comment

I went to upgrade my Xamarin project to Maui and I'm unable to update my applicate using the msix file. I will work perfectly fine if I uninstall the previous version and install.

Error message on updating: App installation failed with error message: Deployment Add operation with target volume C: on Package

There is no further messages in the event viewer.

I've made sure the assembly identity name in the app.manifest is the same as the assembly title in the assemblyInfo.cs.

The identity name, publisher, & phone product id is all the same in the package.appxmanifest.

Is there something else I need to make sure matches in order for the update to occur successfully?

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Troubleshooting packaging, deployment, and query of Windows apps]
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/troubleshooting)
The package failed update, dependency, or conflict validation.
Possible causes:
1,The incoming package conflicts with an installed package.
2,A specified package dependency can't be found.
3,The package doesn't support the correct processor architecture.
For more information, check the `AppXDeployment-Server` event log.

Comment: I did check the AppxDeployment-Server event log.  It showed the exact same message.   Its probably not a dependency as its able to install if you uninstall the previous version, you can install correctly.  So you are right that its probably 1 and I need to have something else matching, the problem is I don't know what else I need to have line up between the two frameworks  to have it update successfully.

Comment: The UWP app and the WinUI3 app are different. So, there may be a conflict between packages. In my opinion, you could only uninstall the previous version and then install new version.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid it, but it looks like thats what we will do.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: If your case has been solved, please help to mark answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Troubleshooting packaging, deployment, and query of Windows apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/troubleshooting)

The package failed update, dependency, or conflict validation.
Possible causes:

The incoming package conflicts with an installed package.

A specified package dependency can't be found.

The package doesn't support the correct processor architecture.

For more informtion, check the `AppXDeployment-Server` event log.

The UWP app and the WinUI3 app are different. So, there may be a conflict between packages. In my opinion, you could only uninstall the previous version and then install new version.

Answer (score 0):

The earlier app was in ".appxbundle" format which was build in Xamarin will contain both x64 and x86 architectures. As Xamarin supported creating both x86 & x64 in a release, now MAUI will support either x86 or x64 in a release, and it is in ".msix" format.

Now, we have to create separate x64 and x86 msix builds and combine them into a single bundle that will be in ".msixbundle" format, we will be able to upgrade the existing app to the Maui app.